# Is there a guava like library for c++?

Tags: c++, guava

Is there a c++ library like guava (java), extending the standard library with a couple of useful methods, classes and shortcuts.

Comment: You can try `boost` http://www.boost.org

Comment: The answer is yes.  Voting to close as not constructive as this question is going to turn into a laundry list of C++ libraries with "a couple of useful methods."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hell yeah. It's called [boost](http://www.boost.org).

> ..one of the most highly regarded and expertly designed C++ library projects in the world.
>   — Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu, C++ Coding Standards